# Linq statement involving index based update of value not working

Tags: linq

In my C# winforms project, I wanted to update a specific index based position in a collection (named List l1 here).

I tried below code:

**l1.Where((s, i1) => i1 == intvalue).Select(s => { if (s > 0) s = -1; return s; };**

I wanted to set value at invalue index to -1 in the list l1, but when I do so with above statement the value in l1 is not changed. Please help! I am new to Linq and have searched the topic 'index based change of value in a collection' everywhere, but can't resolve my problem as it involves BigInteger type and I have so many elements in the list that their total count passes the allowed max value for int type in c#. So when I type l1[intvalue] it says can't convert BigInteger to int for index position.

Thanks

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not for modification.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is Language INtegrated **Queries**. It's purpose is querying data. If you want to modify list item:

```
if (l1[intvalue] > 0)
    l1[intvalue] = -1;
```

Also I'd like to explain why your query is not changing list.

On first step you are selecting list items by some condition. Very strange condition by the way. If you want to select item by index, there is operator `ElementAt`.

Then you are doing projection. I.e. you are calling anonymous method which accepts each selected item and produce some result. Each item passed to that method as `s` argument. And when you are assigning -1 to `s` you are actually assigning value to method argument. That does not affect items in the list. Even if your list will contain items of reference type instead of integers, assigning value to method argument will just change where argument variable points. It will not change references in original list. Though you still can modify items of reference type. But such side-effects in projection methods are not good practice.

Comment: It says can't convert from BigInteger to int for index intvalue as 'intvalue' is BigInteger.

Comment: @vinaych why are you using BigInteger for index in list? Use integer

Comment: There are more elements in the list than Int32.MaxValue, so I need to access those extra elements?

Comment: @vinaych you have more elements than Int32.MaxValue? Why you think so?

Comment: I have added them via collection.ToList() method and set the gcallowverylargeobjects to true value in app.config

Comment: @vinaych with this setting you are allowed to use more than 2GB of memory for your list, but you still limited with 2^31 items count. So, why you are using BigInteger for index?

Comment: @vinaych also `intvalue` name for variable of BigInteger type is **very** confusing and tells nothing about purpose of this variable